# How to create nested fragments and implement FragmentInteractionListener of child fragment in parent fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

How to create nested fragments and implement FragmentInteractionListener of child fragment in parent fragment **NOT** in MainActivity

I'm developing an android app that contains a fragment in main layout. Let's call this '**parentFragment**'.

I also have another fragment within parentFragment. Let's call this fragment '**childFragment**'.

This **childFragment**, have few methods that need to be implemented in the *parentFragment*, **NOT** in *MainActivity*.

This is where I am struggling to achieve. Firstly, is it possible for a Fragment to implement another Fragment's methods? If yes please advise on how to achieve this.

I have created interface for the child fragments to be implemented by ParentFragment.

Here is my MainActivity Class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {  

private NavigationView navigationView;
private DrawerLayout drawer;
private View navHeader;
// and the rest of my variables and setup...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    // Navigation view header
    navHeader = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

    // load nav menu header data
    loadNavHeader();

    // initializing navigation menu
    setUpNavigationView();

    // Load fragments here. In my case HomeFragment
    loadHomeFragment();
}  

/***
 * Returns respected fragment that user
 * selected from navigation menu
 */
private void loadHomeFragment() {
    // selecting appropriate nav menu item
    selectNavMenu();

    // set toolbar title
    setToolbarTitle();

    // load the HomeFragment
    Fragment fragment = getHomeFragment();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);
    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();

    //Closing drawer on item click
    drawer.closeDrawers();        
}

private Fragment getHomeFragment() {
    switch (navItemIndex) {
        case 0:
            // home
            HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
            return fragment;
        case 1:
            // add player
            AddPlayerFragment addPlayerFragment = new AddPlayerFragment();
            return addPlayerFragment;
        case 2:
            // settings
            SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
            return settingsFragment;
        case 3:
            // help
            HelpFragment helpFragment = new HelpFragment();
            return helpFragment;
        case 4:
            // about us
            AboutUsFragment aboutUsFragment = new AboutUsFragment();
            return aboutUsFragment;
        default:
            return new HomeFragment();
    }
}

// and the rest of my logic for navigations, action bar and so on.
// ....  
}
```

HomeFragment is my **parent fragment**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements PlayerProfileFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {  

// players list
private List<Player> playersList;


public HomeFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    // load data here
    playersList = PlayerDao.getInstance(this.getContext()).getAllPlayers();  

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) getView().findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager()));

    return rootView;
}



@Override
public void showMoreData(int playerId) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getContext());
    builder1.setMessage(" showMoreData id = " + playerId);
    builder1.setCancelable(true);
    AlertDialog alert12 = builder1.create();
    alert12.show();
}


private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        if (fm.getFragments() != null) {
            fm.getFragments().clear();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {

        Player player = playersList.get(pos);
        return PlayerProfileFragment.newInstance(player.getId(),  player.getName(), player.getAge(), player.getImagePath());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return playersList.size();
    }
}
}
```

PlayerProfileFragment.java is my **child fragment**.

```
public class PlayerProfileFragment extends Fragment {

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

// the fragment initialization parameters
private static final String ARG_PLAYER_NAME = "playerNameParam";
private static final String ARG_PLAYER_AGE = "playerAgeParam";
private static final String ARG_PLAYER_ID = "playerIdParam";
private static final String ARG_PLAYER_IMAGE_PATH = "playerImagePathParam";

private String playerNameParam;
private String playerAgeParam;
private int playerIdParam;
private String playerImagePathParam;

public PlayerProfileFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static PlayerProfileFragment newInstance(int param1, String param2, int param3, String param4) {
    PlayerProfileFragment fragment = new PlayerProfileFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PLAYER_ID, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PLAYER_NAME, param2);
    args.putString(ARG_PLAYER_AGE, String.valueOf(param3));
    args.putString(ARG_PLAYER_IMAGE_PATH, param4);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    playerNameParam = args.getString(ARG_PLAYER_NAME);
    playerAgeParam = args.getString(ARG_PLAYER_AGE);
    playerIdParam = args.getInt(ARG_PLAYER_ID);
    playerImagePathParam = args.getString(ARG_PLAYER_IMAGE_PATH);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_player_profile, container, false);

    TextView tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_player_profile_name);
    tvName.setText(playerNameParam);

    TextView tvAge = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_player_profile_age);
    tvAge.setText(playerAgeParam + " " + getString(R.string.athlete_info_banner_age_years_label));

    Button showMoreButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_player_profile_show_more_button);

    showMoreButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onButtonShowMorePressed(playerIdParam);
        }
    });

    return v;
}

public void onButtonShowMorePressed(int playerId) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.showMoreData(playerId);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    void uploadPlayerData(int playerId);
    void editPlayer(int playerId);
    void showMoreData(int playerId);
}

}
```

**Please notice that HomeFragment (Parent fragment) does not have onAttach(). Only PlayerProfileFragment has onattach() method. Do I need onAttach() for both fragments?**

Comment: You've given no code, and your specifics are hazy, so I'm guessing at your setup. In the nested `Fragment`'s `onAttach()` method, use the `getParentFragment()` method to get the parent `Fragment` for the listener, instead of trying to cast the `Activity` to your interface. Do note that the platform `Fragment`s only support this from API 17 and up.

Comment: This is my first question on stackoverflow, why did I get -3 for it? Is that by default? or someone actually scored me -3?

Comment: People are scoring you down because you have not provided any code and its unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I added code and also fixed my issue with the help of a friend. AbidK Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I finally got it working. Below is what I had to do:

HomeActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private NavigationView navigationView;
private DrawerLayout drawer;
private View navHeader;
// and the rest of my variables and setup...


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    // Navigation view header
    // load nav menu header data
    loadNavHeader();

    // initializing navigation menu
    setUpNavigationView();

    // Load fragments here. In my case HomeFragment
        loadHomeFragment();

}

/***
 * Load navigation menu header information
 * like background image, profile image
 * name, website, notifications action view (dot)
 */
private void loadNavHeader() {
    // some logic here
}

/***
 * Returns respected fragment that user
 * selected from navigation menu
 */
private void loadHomeFragment() {
    // selecting appropriate nav menu item
    selectNavMenu();

    // set toolbar title
    setToolbarTitle();


            Fragment fragment = getHomeFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);
            fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();


    //Closing drawer on item click
    drawer.closeDrawers();

}

private Fragment getHomeFragment() {
    switch (navItemIndex) {
        case 0:
            // home
            HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
            return fragment;
        case 1:
            // add player
            AddPlayerFragment addPlayerFragment = new AddPlayerFragment();
            return addPlayerFragment;
        case 2:
            // settings
            SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
            return settingsFragment;
        case 3:
            // help
            HelpFragment helpFragment = new HelpFragment();
            return helpFragment;
        case 4:
            // about us
            AboutUsFragment aboutUsFragment = new AboutUsFragment();
            return aboutUsFragment;
        default:
            return new HomeFragment();
    }
}

// and the rest of my logic for navigations, action bar and so on.
// ....
}
```

HomeFragment is my **parent fragment**, please note that it implements **OnFragmentInteractionListener** also using **childFragmentManager** when creating my pagerView.

pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(**getChildFragmentManager()**));

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements PlayerProfileFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
/**
 * The fragment argument representing the item ID that this fragment
 * represents.
 */
private PlayerProfileFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "item_id";

// players list
private List<Player> playersList;


public HomeFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    setupView();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    mListener = (PlayerProfileFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener) getParentFragment();
}


private void setupView(){

    // load data here
    playersList = PlayerDao.getInstance(this.getContext()).getAllPlayers();

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) getView().findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    // using childFragmentManager was part of my solution
    pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

}

@Override
public void showMoreData(int playerId) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getContext());
    builder1.setMessage(" showMoreData id = " + playerId);
    builder1.setCancelable(true);
    AlertDialog alert12 = builder1.create();
    alert12.show();
}

private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        if (fm.getFragments() != null) {
            fm.getFragments().clear();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {

        Player player = playersList.get(pos);
        return PlayerProfileFragment.newInstance(player.getId(),  player.getName(), player.getAge(), player.getImagePath());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return playersList.size();
    }
}
}
```

PlayerProfileFragment class is my **child fragment**. Please note that, This is also part of my solution. Use **getParentFragment**() to initialise *mListener*

**mListener = (PlayerProfileFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener) getParentFragment();**

```
public class PlayerProfileFragment extends Fragment {

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

// the fragment initialization parameters
private static final String ARG_PLAYER_NAME = "playerNameParam";
private static final String ARG_PLAYER_AGE = "playerAgeParam";
private static final String ARG_PLAYER_ID = "playerIdParam";
private static final String ARG_PLAYER_IMAGE_PATH = "playerImagePathParam";

private String playerNameParam;
private String playerAgeParam;
private int playerIdParam;
private String playerImagePathParam;

public PlayerProfileFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static PlayerProfileFragment newInstance(int param1, String param2, int param3, String param4) {
    PlayerProfileFragment fragment = new PlayerProfileFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PLAYER_ID, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PLAYER_NAME, param2);
    args.putString(ARG_PLAYER_AGE, String.valueOf(param3));
    args.putString(ARG_PLAYER_IMAGE_PATH, param4);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    playerNameParam = args.getString(ARG_PLAYER_NAME);
    playerAgeParam = args.getString(ARG_PLAYER_AGE);
    playerIdParam = args.getInt(ARG_PLAYER_ID);
    playerImagePathParam = args.getString(ARG_PLAYER_IMAGE_PATH);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    // This is also part of my solution: getParentFragment() -- very important
    mListener = (PlayerProfileFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener) getParentFragment();

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_player_profile, container, false);

    TextView tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_player_profile_name);
    tvName.setText(playerNameParam);

    TextView tvAge = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_player_profile_age);
    tvAge.setText(playerAgeParam + " " + getString(R.string.athlete_info_banner_age_years_label));

    Button showMoreButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_player_profile_show_more_button);

    showMoreButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onButtonShowMorePressed(playerIdParam);
        }
    });

    return v;
}

public void onButtonShowMorePressed(int playerId) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.showMoreData(playerId);
    }
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.     
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    void showMoreData(int playerId);
}

}
```

I hope it helps you guys. Let me know if you have any question.